# Any way to run a user script on suspend/resume in KDE4?

Tags: debian, kde-4, suspend

I have the desire to run a script as the logged in user immediately before a hibernate (suspend to disk) operation, and immediately after a resume with KDE4.

I know that I can put a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` that will do this, but such a script must be non-interactive, and will run as root.

I need this script to run as a the user logged in to KDE, and the post-resume script would ideally be interactive.

I can see where I can run a script on suspect in KDE, but it's imperfect:

> **System Settings** -> **Power Management** -> **Advanced Settings** -> **Configure Notifications**

This allows me to specify a command to run on resume, however...

1. It doesn't appear to distinguish between Suspend to RAM and Suspend to disk (alone, not a deal breaker, but I really only need to run my command on suspend-to-disk)
2. It doesn't have any option to run a script on resume, which is actually the most important part I need.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to accomplish is to auto un-mount my Windows partition when I hibernate, so that the filesystem will be consistent whenever I boot into Windows.  This is best done as the user, and with interaction, because the partition is encrypted with TrueCrypt, and I prefer entering the passphrase after resuming, rather than having it stored on the filesystem.

I do realize that I can automate much of this if I'm willing to run as root, and non-interactively, so please don't suggest these as alternatives.  I may end up doing that, but that's not what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Only similar thing I've found are hooks on lower level provided by `pm` and `systemd` hooks:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_Management#Hooks_in_.2Fusr.2Flib.2Fsystemd.2Fsystem-sleep